# XCUITest: find CollectionView inside TableView failed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I'm trying to monitoring UI change of Collection View inside Table View for UI testing, but i can't seem to find the solution. I have tried to do many things, one of them is `app.tables.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).collectionViews.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).tap() code here`, but nothing works. Thanks.

Comment: Please add more context and code so that we can understand your problem

Comment: I'm trying to listen for UI change of a Collection View inside a Table View for UITesting in XCUITest, I can easily listen for UI change in table view because it has no parent, but I can't even search for the Collection View inside the Table View and the record function of the XCode will stop working once i tap the Collection View. Regarding the code, it works fine as expected, but the one I've been trying to solve is the XCUITest not the functionality of my code.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem, by using `app.tables.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .any).element(boundBy: 0)` you can search for the Collection View inside Table View